# How to use both a variable and a changed variable in the same command

Tags: bash, shell

in simple I want to execute one command over many files and am trying to do that with a `for do done` loop.

`dwebp foo.webp -o ./PNGs/foo.png`
is the command that I want to execute over all files that correspond to `*.webp` in my current directory.

I am able to get the `/PNGs/foo.png` working by doing

`for f in *.webp; do echo "$f" "${f%.webp}.png"; done`. I'm now however not able to use `$f` as the original file name (which is still needed).

The fact that I am using the `${f%.webp}.png` without really understanding why or how it works doesn't help...
So, does anyone know how I'd be able to run the `dwebp foo.webp -o ./PNGs/foo.png` command with a `for do done` loop, or a better way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: `"${f%.webp}.png"` doesn't change `f`'s value. You can still use `$f` as the original filename.

Answer (score 2):

For an explanation on how `${f%.webp}` works, see [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

`${f%.webp}` does **not** modify the value of `${f}`, consider:

```
$ f=foo.webp
$ echo "${f%.webp}.png"
foo.png
$ echo "${f}"
foo.webp
```

Net result is that you could try something like:

```
for f in *.webp
do
    echo "${f}"
    dwebp "${f}" -o "./PNGs/${f%.webp}.png"
done
```

Or if you'll need to perform the same parameter expansion a few times, you can do it once and store in a new variable, eg:

```
for f in *.webp
do
    newf="${f%.webp}.png"
    echo "original file : ${f} / new file : ${newf}"

    dwebp "${f}" -o "./PNGs/${newf}"
done
```